# How to construct a ring isomorphism in this case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let (A, +, $\times$) be a ring with unity 1 and (A, $\oplus$, $\otimes$) be a ring (already proved to be), where the operations are defined as:

- a $\oplus$ b = a + b + 1
- a $\otimes$ b = (a $\times$ b) + a + b

We want to formally verify if (A, +, $\times$) and (A, $\oplus$, $\otimes$) are isomorphic.

My question is: is there a path to do is? I know that I must find a bijective homomorphism, but I don't know any ideas to construct such function given these rings. I tried but can't find any promising ideas, so any general light on this type of problem would be of great value.

Comment: For the specific case, which is essentially defining $a\oplus b=f(f^{-1}(a)+f^{-1}(b))$ and $a\times b=f(f^{-1}(a)\times f^{-1}(b))$ for some nonsensical bijection $f:A\to A$, I don't think there's any fancy idea except making the right guess. Try finding the units and the inverses, and you might get it. Most other cases come from more natural ideas and there are more polished techinques.

Comment: Is $a\to a\pm 1$ an isomorphism from one ring to the other one? (It is enough to show the compatibility of operations...)

Comment: Hey man, your comment gave me a good insight @dan_fulea.
It is nice to see that a $\oplus$ b = (a + 1) + (b + 1) + (-1) and that a $\otimes$ b = (a + 1) $\times$ (b + 1) + (-1). I think I can work out formally from here

Answer (score 1):

The comment of @dan_fuela above gave me an insight and I got to answer the question, so I am writing it down here.

Seeing

- (a $\oplus$ b) as (a + 1) + (b + 1) + (-1), and
- (a $\otimes$ b) as (a + 1) $\times$ (b + 1) + (-1)

we are inspired to define f: A $\rightarrow$ A as f(a) = a + (-1).
And indeed, it is easy to follow that f(a + b) = f(a) $\oplus$ f(b) and that f(a $\times$ b) = f(a) $\otimes$ f(b).

Moreover, if f(a) = f(b), then a + (-1) = b + (-1), so a = b. Thus f is injective.
And if b $\in$ A, we can take a $:=$b+1 so f(a) = a + (-1) = b. Thus f is surjective.

Therefore, f is bijective and we got ourselves an isomorphism.